# What is the meaning of: Base(int x): x{x}{}?

Tags: c++

I was going through some tutorial online and found one c++ snippet which i am unable to figure out what exactly that snippet is doing.
I need info like what this concept is called and why it is used.

Code is:

```
class Base{
    int x;
public:
    Base(){}
    Base(int x): x{x}{} // this line i am unable to understand.
};
```

I want to know what this 5th line does and what is happening in compiler while compiling.

Comment: Usually online tutorials are bad for learning and waste of time. Invest your efforts for reading one of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) written by professionals.

Comment: @S.M. That list could do with some updating by now ;) I think this is a good video though : "The best parts of C++" by jason turner. It at least explains a lot about references and the standard library : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iz5Qx18H6lg

Comment: @PepijnKramer The list is always actual. It is updated recently, edited on Jul 4 at 22:53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start off with the following:

1. the : after the corresponding constructor in the definition represents "Member Initialization".
2. x is an integer
3. C++ you are able to initialize primitive datatypes utilizing curly braces. See: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/declaring-a-variable-with-braces-in-cpp
4. So therefore the x{x} is initializing x to the passed in value of the constructor.
5. the last {} are for the constructor function call itself.

Comment: Your line 4 is incorrect. It is initializing `Base::x`, the member variable, to the value of `x` passed as the argument to the constructor. While they're both called `x`, in this context the compiler distinguishes between them.

Comment: You're right its a constructor call with passed in argument. Will adjust. Hence why it's better to this->x = x. Or more meaningful names

Comment: ...or different names.

Answer (score 3):

It's this :

```
Base(int x) : 
    // initialization of members
    x{ x }  // aggregate initialization of member x with parameter x
            // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
{
    // empty function
}
```

Comment: Nit.  Should be `// aggregate initialization of member x with parameter x`.  An **argument** is what is passed in at the callsite as the value to the **parameter**.  (Mnemonic:  an argument is to a parameter, as an automobile is to a parking spot.)

Comment: Eljay yeah that's me knowing pretty much how it all works, not always spot on with the terminolgy. I'll keep working on it ;)